# Can the Parse jar be reduced to have fewer methods?

Tags: parse-platform

Because of the Android 64k max method limit, I'm trying to reduce the number of methods provided by the Parse Android SDK. Parse-1.5.0.jar has some 4,500+ methods. Any suggestions?

Removing the SDK and using the REST APIs is a possibility, but may be somewhat time consuming.

Comment: Facing the same issue, you may turn to ProGuard, but working with it active will increase your build time.

Answer (score 1):

Try using ProGuard and leave out the idea of using REST APIs... Honestly I never heard about such a workaround for such a problem 0_o

Just tell ProGuard to shrink your code, skipping additional features like obuscation if you don't want to slow down the deploy. The `proguard-project.txt` file will be more or less like this:

```
-dontoptimize
-dontobfuscate
-allowaccessmodification
-dontpreverify

# The remainder of this file is identical to the non-optimized version
# of the Proguard configuration file (except that the other file has
# flags to turn off optimization).

-dontusemixedcaseclassnames
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
-verbose

-keep public class com.google.vending.licensing.ILicensingService
-keep public class com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService

# For native methods, see http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/examples.html#native
-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    native <methods>;
}

# keep setters in Views so that animations can still work.
# see http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/examples.html#beans
-keepclassmembers public class * extends android.view.View {
   void set*(***);
   *** get*();
}

# We want to keep methods in Activity that could be used in the XML attribute onClick
-keepclassmembers class * extends android.app.Activity {
   public void *(android.view.View);
}

# For enumeration classes, see http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/examples.html#enumerations
-keepclassmembers enum * {
    public static **[] values();
    public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
}

-keep class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
  public static final android.os.Parcelable$Creator *;
}

-keepclassmembers class **.R$* {
    public static <fields>;
}

# The support library contains references to newer platform versions.
# Don't warn about those in case this app is linking against an older
# platform version.  We know about them, and they are safe.
-dontwarn android.support.**
```